# How do I get my Core Data entity's attributes to be visible in objective-c unit tests

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unit-testing, core-data

I am trying to unit-test a mixed objective-c & Swift app that uses a Core Data model. The model has a **Location** entity that contains a few attributes. Other than a FetchIndex element, it is very straightforward

The unit tests are written in objective-c. I can set up the Core Data stack (in a singleton class called DataManager), I can get it to seed the Persistent Store with values, I can get it to delete all the "records".

I can even, using KVC, access the individual attributes of the entity.

The problem is that I can't access the entity's attributes by name in the unit tests. In the actual app, I can access them because of the `#import "MyProjectName-Swift.h"` statement, which "magically" makes the attributes visible. But trying to import that into the unit test doesn't work, Xcode can't find the file.

The Core Data model is set up to use the 'Class definition' option, which means that there are no visible Swift files or objective-c files containing the model definition. I understand they get generated behind the scenes.

I tried to change this to 'Category/extension' and the Swift files were added to the project, but importing them into the objective-c unit tests, kinda expectedly, did not work.

I then changed the code-generation option from Swift to objective-c. This generated 2 objective-c class files (Location+CoreDataClass.h and .m, and Location+CoreDataProperties.h and .m). I was sure this would provide me with the proper file to import...

But it didn't, because the Location+CoreDataProperties.h tries to import the Location.h file. And that file doesn't get generated/is nowhere to be found.

There are "dreaded" alternatives, and those are to rewrite the entire Core Data stack in Swift. Or, drop the unit tests...

I am guessing that all this needs to work is an #import statement of some kind.

Would appreciate any tips at all!

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

#import "DataManager.h"

@interface DataManagerTests : XCTestCase
@property (strong, nonatomic) DataManager *dataManagerInstance;
@end


@implementation DataManagerTests

- (void)setUp {
self.dataManagerInstance = [DataManager sharedDataManager];
} (

- (void)testSeeding
{  
    NSPersistentContainer *currentContainer = self.dataManagerInstance.persistentContainer;   
    NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext = [currentContainer newBackgroundContext];
    
    [self.dataManagerInstance deleteAllRecordsFromPersistentStoreUsingBackgroundContext:backgroundContext]; //OK
    [self.dataManagerInstance seedEmptyPersistentStoreWithLocationsArrayOfDictionaries:[self.dataManagerInstance wellformedSeedLocationsDictionaryArray]]; //OK
    
    [self.dataManagerInstance debugPrintAllLocations]; //OK
    
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Location"];
    NSSortDescriptor *ascendingDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"identifier" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ascendingDescriptor]];

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [currentContainer.viewContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

    for (id location in fetchedObjects) {
        NSLog(@"TEST - %@", [location valueForKey:@"identifier"]);  //OK
    }

//THE PROBLEM IS HERE:
    for (Location *location in fetchedObjects) { //Compiler ERROR - Use of undeclared identifier 'Location' 
        NSLog(@"identifier->%@< name->%@<- metroarea->%@<-",location.identifier, location.name, location.metroarea );  //Compiler ERROR - Use of undeclared identifier 'Location' 
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution 2 minutes after posting - and after spending the entire day looking. The sought-after import statement is this:

```
#import "MyProjectNameTests-Swift.h
```

Xcode will show you the exact name of the Swift header file for unit tests in the Build settings. Select the test target, and look for the 'Swift Compiler - Code generation' section (search for Swift using the search bar).

Just as for the normal target, the Swift header file itself is invisible in the project navigator.